# Generate feature posts using middleman

Tags: ruby, erb, middleman, static-site

I am trying to make a section on my home page for featured posts like you might have in Wordpress, I have placed `featured: true` in the articles frontmatter and I am then trying to generate the posts using:

**Article.md**

```
---
title: Example Article
date: 2012-01-01
published: true
description: This is a very nice article you should read!
tags: example
featured: true
---

## This is the article
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% blog.articles.select {|a| a.data[:featured] }.each do |article| %>
    <h2><%= link_to article.title, article %> <span><%= article.date.strftime('%b %e') %></span></h2>
    <!-- use article.summary(250) if you have Nokogiri available to show just
         the first 250 characters -->
    <%= article.body %>
<% end %>
```

I have played around with `if` `unless` to try check if the data is true but I had no luck, I also tried `[:featured => true]` and other variation but no dice.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Never Mind I figured it out, I just had a few things minor things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This already only displays results where `featured = true`

```
<% blog.articles.select {|a| a.data[:featured] }.each do |article| %>
    <h2><%= link_to article.title, article %> <span><%= article.date.strftime('%b %e') %></span></h2>
    <!-- use article.summary(250) if you have Nokogiri available to show just
         the first 250 characters -->
    <%= article.body %>
<% end %>
```